what do reinforcing and ridicule mean here?

The danger often facing authors of satirical works is that if the
audience is not  discerning enough to get  the joke, the piece may end
up (i)____ the behavior it was trying to (ii)____
Blank(i)
reinforcing
depicting
elucidating
Blank(ii)
conceal
support
ridicule

My answer is depicting and conceal.
Others said reinforcing and ridicule.
What do the two words mean in the sentence then?

Your interpretation "kinda" makes sense, but unquestionably that's not what was meant. The right answer is as others have told you - reinforcing + ridicule. Logically, if the comedian starts talking about some behaviour (with intent to mock it), he's hardly concealing it, is he? What your text means is that if a dumb audience member doesn't get the joke, he may think the comic is endorsing the behaviour, which may reinforce his erroneous idea that the behaviour is in fact acceptable.

As when Jonathon Swift proposed that the Irish could solve their potato blight famine by breeding children for food. Obviously a joke, unless someone is so dumb they go down the local orphanage looking to buy a fat child for Sunday lunch!

@FumbleFingers - I'm thinking also of Warren Mitchell, who satirically played an ignorant racist bigot in a UK TV sitcom, only to find himself cheered in the streets by skinheads, builders, taxi drivers, white-van-men, etc. Jonathan Swift was a bit of a weirdo and no mistake - greatly obsessed with defecation, I read once. One of my favourite writers, all the same.

The British novelist, writer, and painter, Percy Wyndham Lewis (whom the poet T.S. Eliot called "the greatest prose writer of my generation") ran into the issue where some readers did not understand that a work was satire.  Some of his books have been removed from library shelves.

@MichaelHarvey: Alf Garnett wouldn't have been funny (and engaging) if he hadn't reflected at least some part of "us" at the time. I wasn't aware of the 1968 movie Till Death Us Do Part until I came across it a couple of years ago. Brought tears to my eyes, so it did!

@FumbleFingers - in 'at least some part of "us"', I think you are acknowledging that someone can be a member of society without having some of the more obnoxious views held by some members of it - Alf Garnett reminded me of a number of relatives and neighbours. I don't know anyone who is like Borat, and I used to think the character was funny...

Start with the idea that satire ridicules something. This may be by exaggeration, such as H. C. Andersen's The Emperor's New Clothes ridicules conspicuous consumption.
The goal of ridicule is to point out a foible, and convince others that the situation needs to be changed. However, someone not understanding the errors shown might repeat them, i.e., reinforcing the flaw.
